# Maven Dependency Errors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am having issues with Maven Eclipse integration.
I am able to compile the project using Run as profiles and everything is fine from command prompt too

But in Eclipse Markers I am getting below error when I update/compile

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for hiddeninfo:jar:27.0.0-${env}-SNAPSHOT: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer hiddeninfo:pom:27.0.0-${env}-SNAPSHOT from http ://hiddeninfo/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of public has elapsed or updates are forced.
>
> Original error: Could not transfer artifact hiddeninfo:pom:27.0.0-${env}-SNAPSHOT from/to public (http ://hiddeninfo/nexus/content/groups/public): Illegal character in path at index 106: http ://hiddeninfo/nexus/content/groups/public/hiddeninfo-27.0.0-${envs}-SNAPSHOT.pom

I removed Repository folder and updated again. Still same issue.
And I am pretty sure that the reason behind this "$env" which we actually pass as argument.

In a command prompt, this command works:

```
mvn clean install -Penv-itt
```

but the following command throws the same error as above:

```
mvn clean install
```

So how can I modify the Maven update project to accept arguments or another work-around to get rid of these errors from Eclipse?

Comment: Could you have a look at the "Illegal character in path at index 106: http ://hiddeninfo/nexus/content/groups/public/hiddeninfo-27.0.0-${envs}-SNAPSHOT.pom" and see if the error persists if you fix the character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/)? If so, then you can activate a profile for a particular project by looking at the properties and selecting *Maven > Active Maven Profiles*.

The fact that the following command line works:

```
mvn clean install -P env-itt
```

means that your POM must have a profile listed called `env-itt`. Presumably this profile  defines a Maven property called `env`, which explains why your build breaks when you haven't activated the profile.

Hence, in your case, you should specify `env-itt` to trigger the correct profile.

Comment: What should I mention in Active Maven profiles. Can you please post step by step to create profile and attach to project. Thanks

Comment: @NitinGurram I've added some further explanation to my answer. If you have any questions, you'll need to edit your question to include your POM file so that I can help further.